# What does "to call" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

What does call mean in this sentence?

> Democratic front-runner Hillary Clinton won her party's primary in Mississippi, but her battle with Bernie Sanders in Michigan is too close **to call**.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is *to predict the result of a future event (especially an election or a vote)*

Answer (score 0):

To call means to make a judgement. It is often used about ball games:a line call is a decision about whether the ball landed inside or outside the line defining an area of the court. If you say that something is too close to call, it means that it is impossible to make a judgement. Since the 1960s, political pundits have started usin it in advance of the result, to mean thst it is impossible to predict the outcome.